# .net core application throws exception while introducing Form tag

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm learning c# .net core using freecodecamp youtube video. The razor page works fine until i introduced a form tag. When i remove the form tag the application runs fine. On introducing form tag the application throw error. I'm new to razor page and .net core. I'm using VS Code as editor.

Exception:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.

Code:

```
@page
@model brugen.Pages.BookList.IndexModel
@{

} 

<br/>

<div class="container row p-0 m-0">
    <div class="col-9">
        <h2 class="text-info">BOOk List</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <a class="btn btn-info form-control text-white">Create New </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 border p-3 mt-3">
         <Form method="post">

            @if ( Model.Books.Count() > 0 )
            {

            }
            else
            {
                <p>No Books Available</p> 
            }
        </Form> 
    </div> 

</div>
```

startup.cs

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

Comment: This might sound odd, but do you have any data protection middleware in your app?

Comment: No I didn't add anything like that.Edited the question by adding startup.cs

Comment: I've seen this exact issue before when using a separately hosted identity server that used data protection. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804689/490282) detailed what my issue was.

Comment: The application works fine on converting the form method value from Post to get. Not sure about the reason behind.