# Share authentication cookies between two different ASP.NET Core web applications

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-5, data-protection, asp.net-core-5.0

I have two apps, one written in ASP.NET Core 2.1, one with ASP.NET Core 5 (.NET 5). And both apps are using `identityserver4` to do authentication and using ASP.NET Core data protection API to encrypt the authentication cookie.

I am trying to share the same cookie between the two apps. Meaning the cookie issued by one server can be read by another server, and vice versa.

I am using below code to make sure the two apps are sharing the same keys

```
services.AddDataProtection()
   .PersistKeysToFileSystem(AppConfiguration.PersistKeysDirectory);
```

The two apps will be deployed on to the same machine, point to the same directory. But it's not working. I still get `ticket unprotect failed` error.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's not the case. The keys can be shared between versions, provided that the two apps sharing the same application name and same directory like below

```
services.AddDataProtection()
   .SetApplicationName({config.SharedAppName})
   .PersistKeysToFileSystem(config.PersistKeysDirectory);
```

See [github issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2205#issuecomment-424253606) and also [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704499/915147)

The reason is that the two apps are not identical, it's not two replica of the same app, but two different apps. I reckon that if `ApplicationName` is not set, `ASP.NET Core` will use a some kind of file checksum to determine the `ApplicationName`. So two different apps must set the same `ApplicationName` to make it work